# Simple file/content management tool in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file

We are looking for simple file management tool written in asp.net.

Requirements:
  -folder manipulation (create/copy/move/delete)
  -file manipulation (upload/download/copy/move/delete)
  -user management  (login/add/delete/edit/logout)

Is there something like this?

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Windows SharePoint Services v 3

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb400747

Note: Its tool to manage folders, file stored in a content management database system and not on filesystem.